# How to create a camera that follows the player?

Tags: camera

I have a javascript game where I use a tile grid somewhat like this:

```
var tiles = [
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1]
];
```

I want a camera to follow the player and when the player moves off the map, shift the camera over to new tiles. Even better just a map that follows the player.

Comment: You should describe your camera interface. Is it some object that's easly movable?

Comment: Are you using DOM or a canvas to render your grid?

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you want to follow player, the way to do this is to update camera's position after every player position update:

```
for( var i = 0; i < DIMENSIONS; i++ ) {
    camera.position[i] = player.position[i] + camera.offset[i];
}
```

Offset should be set in your game editor or in game init, as the difference between player and camera initial positions ( which were set up in game editor ):

```
for( var i = 0; i < DIMENSIONS; i++ ) {
    camera.offset[i] = camera.position[i] - player.position[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add map and objects to a container.

Example: container.x = -camera.x (illusion camera moved through world)

a = OBJECT location

b = TARGET location

t = decimal between 0 and 1

```
function lerp(a, b, t)
  return a + (b - a) * t
end
```

Return INTEGER to move from a to b. As a is closer to b, integer will become smaller (deceleration).

camera.x = 100

target.x = 200

spring = 0.6

```
integer = lerp(camera.x,target.x,spring)
camera.x += integer
container.x = -camera.x
```